# How to protect the case of a letter?

Tags: capitalization

Simple task here: I want to use the `\MakeUppercase{}` command, but I have some text that must be protected to remain lower case. Specifically, elemental symbols (e.g. `PbI\textsubscript{2}`, where the 'b' needs to remain lower case. Is there some way of protecting lower case letters from `\MakeUppercase{}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are we talking about just one lowercase letter, or could there be several lowercase letters that must be protected from being converted to uppercase?

Comment: input the `b` as `\lowercase{b}`.

Comment: If you're happy to switch to `\MakeTextUppercase` with the [`textcase`](https://ctan.org/pkg/textcase) package then you can use `\NoCaseChange{...}` to protect the case. (I think there's a package option to redefine `\MakeUppercase` as `\MakeTextUppercase`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a macro for it. I suggest considering `chemformula` for chemistry documents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula} % also loads xparse

\NewDocumentCommand{\LI}{}{\ch{PbI2}}

\begin{document}

Here is lead iodide \LI{} and
\MakeUppercase{also \LI{} here}

Here's a reaction: \ch{Pb + I2 -> PbI2}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\newcommand` would not work, but `\NewDocumentCommand` makes the macro safe against `\MakeUppercase`.

[image]

Comment: @jkmey If you use `\ch{PbI2}` in text that ends up inside `\MakeUppercase`, the `b` would be uppercased as well. By hiding it in a “protected” macro, `\MakeUppercase` will do nothing to it.